# Pikepdf error: "RuntimeError: unable to load openssl legacy provider"

Tags: python-3.x, pikepdf

When I try top open a password protected pdf file using pikepdf it runs gives me this error: RuntimeError: unable to load openssl legacy provider

```
def crack(self, pdf_file="",  numbers_only="n", possible_length=10, **kwargs):
        file_exist = path.exists(pdf_file)
        cracking = True
        if file_exist:
            if numbers_only == "y" or numbers_only == "Y":
                while cracking:
                    password = [choice(NUMBERS) for _ in range(possible_length)]
                    password = "".join(password)
                    print(f"[SYSTEM] Cracking {pdf_file}: {password}", end="\r")
                    try:
                        Pdf.open(pdf_file, password=password)
                        print("PASSWORD FOUND: " + password)
                        cracking = False
                    except:
                        continue

        else:
            print(f"[ERROR] File does not exists ${pdf_file}")
            sys.exit()
```

I was expecting that it would try and open the file.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to install OpenSSL in your machine
If you are on macOS

```
brew install openssl
```

for windows you can find installer on their official website - https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

for linux based os, use

```
sudo apt install openssl
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response unfortunately that didn't fix the problem I still got the same error message. I'm using mac os by the way.

Comment: Did you restart the terminal or made sure the path is set to openssl? Because this is the major issue people face. If not then You might nee to look at versions